# Quasar’s Input component TextFiled (q-input) have problem in converting input - text in to upper-case

Tags: vue.js, quasar

When you trying to convert the input string into Upper-case using '**upper-case**' property in quasar's **q-input** (Textfield), it'll repeat previously entered text(string) again and again.you can see this in blow gif.

[image: upper-case issues in input textfield]

the code snippet is as given below:

[image]

if I remove upper-case property from q-input then this issue also didn't appear. also, this particular issue faces in all kind of **tablet** and larger screen devices only. in a small device, this issue can't be generated.

Answer (score 1):

As second way try following:

```
<q-input class="uppercase" type="text"></q-input>
<style>
    .uppercase input {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This is not doing exactly the same but work for me with some additional fixes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<q-input :value=mytext type="text" @input= "val => { mytext = val.toUpperCase() }" />
```

`mytext` is your v-model.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.